# ¿Restful Service opening socket connection and reuses the same connection in all requests?

Tags: spring, sockets, rest, jakarta-ee, tcp

I connect to a transactional server that is a Socket Server. As requirement are asked to have only one connection to the socket, and in this same connection all transactions are sent.
I'm working with Java EE, Spring, Jboss server.
The idea is to create a restful service, so other applications to connect and send transactions.
Is it possible to open a client socket connection, and in the same connection open to send and receive messages client - server?

I have no idea how to do it, because every time you invoke the service rest, the application will attempt to create a new socket connection to the server, and will not reuse an already open connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want open just one socket and keep it open you can use incase you have Spring 4.0 websockets http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Using websocket you can create just one TCP/IP connection between client/server and keep it open during the whole time make it bidirectional transactions and being reused for all transactions that you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the socket server is from a third part, then I can't use websockets.

Comment: Then you can use DeferredResult from Spring, this Future object will be pending after the request it´s finish then until deferredResult.isDone() you block the rest of transactions make it sequentials. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html

Comment: Do you think do the following? SocketServer <= Java SE Socket Client with Persistence connection <= ActiveMQ <= Rest Service J2EE